# How to install wine in Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: apt, wine, 19.10

Recently shifted to Ubuntu from Windows .First time user.

I tried a couple of methods to install wine as mentioned in the forums .

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
wget -qO - https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ disco main'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

gives the following error  :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package winehq-stable
```

Can anyone help please ?

Comment: https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

Answer (score 10):

You are using Ubuntu 19.10 which is codenamed *eoan*, not *disco*, so it should be changed from *disco* to *eoan* in the third command too. winehq-stable is not available in 19.10, so instead of winehq-stable install winehq-staging which is the most recent testing wine version. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
sudo apt-key add winehq.key
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ eoan main'
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-staging
```

If apt complains about missing dependencies, install them, then repeat the last two steps (update and install).

Comment: I'll give you the upvote for the copy/paste from Wiki :)

Comment: @EODCraftStaff This is getting interesting. I didn't even read the [wiki](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu), I figured out the revised code in my head. Then I checked back in the wiki and found an error in it for 19.10 version because it doesn't have the stable branch yet (maybe because it hasn't been updated yet), although the wiki says it does.

Comment: Must Be Nice! I have to look up everything :(

Comment: So iv got to wait right ? Until they upload the stable version ? 
Bear with me :D Iv got no idea what I'm doing here ...

Comment: winehq-staging is the most recent testing version of the same wine package as winehq-stable, so you can either replace winehq-stable with winehq-staging or else wait until winehq-stable for 19.10 is released. Whenever that will happen I don't know.19.10 is only supported for 9 months.

Comment: "The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-devel : Depends: wine-devel (= 4.18~eoan)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."

thats the new development ... Is this related to libfaudio0- as pointed out by some forums- If so , whadoido ? 
Care to help . . anyone ..someone ?

Comment: First try `sudo apt install winehq-staging` (without `--install-recommends` option). If that doesn't work try [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/)

Comment: I got a dependency nightmare with: wine-staging-i386:i386 : Depends: ...

Answer (score -2):

**Wrong package name. Try just 'wine' or 'wine1.6' or 'wine1.8'.**

**Installing WineHQ packages for  Ubuntu 19.10**

*If your system is 64 bit, enable 32 bit architecture (if you haven't already):*

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

*Download and add the repository key:*

```
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
sudo apt-key add winehq.key
```

*Add the repository:*

*Ubuntu 19.10*

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ **eoan** main'
```

*Update packages:*

```
sudo apt update
```

*Then install the packages:*

*Stable branch*

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

if Wrong package name. Try just 'wine' or 'wine4.5' or 'wine4'

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends wine-stable
```