# Wine: How to use SAPI 5 voices for TTS application “Balabolka”?

Tags: wine, 19.10, text-to-speech

I recently installed Wine [according to this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1183396/845469) and [“Balabolka”](http://www.cross-plus-a.com/de/balabolka.htm), a very good TTS program that runs smoothly under Windows, afterwards. Wine did not install SAPI 4 or SAPI 5  voices which are required to use the program. So, I downloaded a free [German (Steffi)](https://www.mwsreader.com/de/sprecher/) and a free [British English (Emily)](http://mikesttsblog.altervista.org/tts-voices/) SAPI 5 voice and installed them as well.

Unfortunately, Balabolka does not recognise these voices although they are installed. What can I do? Usually, Balabolka should be able to detect the voices automatically. But this does not work under Ubuntu. Furthermore, Balabolka does not seem to have an option which enables the user to manually select the installed voices if they are not detected by Balabolka itself.

---

**Edit 1:** I just saw that there is an option where one could (theoretically) select different voices but the option is greyed out.

---

**Edit 2:** It seems to be possible [to install SAPI 4 voices so that Balabolka recognises them](https://askubuntu.com/a/867774/845469) but I do not know how this can be achieved. I tried installing a SAPI 4 voice but it did not show up when I started the program. Having a SAPI 4  voice, however, would be at least better than having no solution at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find any way (currently) to make the program work with *SAPI 4/5* voices, but you can work with some of *Microsoft Speech Platform* voices.

1. Create 32-bit Wine Prefix:

   ```
   WINEPREFIX="$HOME/prefix32" WINEARCH=win32 wine wineboot
   ```
2. Install Balabolka:

   ```
   cd "$HOME/prefix32/drive_c/Program Files/"
   wget http://balabolka.site/balabolka_portable.zip
   unzip balabolka_portable.zip
   ```
3. Test if program works:

   ```
   WINEPREFIX="$HOME/prefix32" wine "$HOME/prefix32/drive_c/Program Files/Balabolka/balabolka.exe"
   ```
4. Install Microsoft Speech Platform voice files (specifically [x86 Package](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27225) and [Runtime Languages](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27224)), I will choose ZiraPro, however you can install other voice files:

   ```
   wget https://download.microsoft.com/download/A/6/4/A64012D6-D56F-4E58-85E3-531E56ABC0E6/x86_SpeechPlatformRuntime/SpeechPlatformRuntime.msi
   WINEPREFIX="$HOME/prefix32" wine msiexec /i SpeechPlatformRuntime.msi

   wget https://download.microsoft.com/download/4/0/D/40D6347A-AFA5-417D-A9BB-173D937BEED4/MSSpeech_TTS_en-US_ZiraPro.msi
   WINEPREFIX="$HOME/prefix32" wine msiexec /i MSSpeech_TTS_en-US_ZiraPro.msi
   ```
5. Install `winetricks`:

   ```
   sudo apt install winetricks
   ```
6. Install `msxml6`:

   ```
   WINEPREFIX="$HOME/prefix32" winetricks msxml6
   ```
7. Check if this program works. (Repeat step 3 and choose *Microsoft Speech Platform* Tab in the program)

Hope this helps...

P.S. To install other voice files, go to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27224, download and then install with:

```
WINEPREFIX="$HOME/prefix32" wine msiexec /i <filename of the downloaded package>
```

Source:

[How do I create a 32-bit WINE prefix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177192/how-do-i-create-a-32-bit-wine-prefix)

https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=34389

Comment: I am encountering some problems when writing `WINEPREFIX="$HOME/prefix32" wine SpeechPlatformRuntime.msi`. After writing this, the following lines show up: (1): `000b:fixme:winediag:start_process Wine Staging 4.20 is a testing version containing experimental patches.`, (2): `000b:fixme:winediag:start_process Please mention your exact version when filing bug reports on winehq.org.`, (3): `0009:err:module:__wine_process_init failed to load L"C:\\Program Files\\SpeechPlatformRuntime.msi", error c000012f`. By the way: There is an error in your answer. It has to be `Program Files` without ``\``.

Comment: [This](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=32004) might be helpful.

Comment: @Nemgathos, every space should be escaped with backslash, so there should be no error with Program Files. And about the main problem, what about running `WINEPREFIX="$HOME/prefix32" wine msiexec \i SpeechPlatformRuntime.msi`?

Comment: Now, the third line looks like this: `0009:fixme:msi:MsiMessageBoxW 00000000 L"Windows Installer 4.5.6001.22308\n\nAufruf:\nmsiexec Befehl {erforderliche Parameter} [zus\00e4tzliche Parameter]\n\nProdukt installieren:\n\t/i {Paket|Produktcode} [Eigenschaft]\n\t/package {Paket|Produktcode} [Eigenschaft]\n\t/a Paket [Eigenschaft]\nInstallation reparieren:\n\t/f[p|o|e|"... (null) 0 00000407 00000000` Also, [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iw0IZ.jpg) showed up.

Comment: (Aufruf = call; Befehl = command; erforderliche/zusätzliche Parameter = required/additional parameters; Produkt installieren = install product; Paket = packet; Produktcode = product code; Eigenschaft = feature/preoperty)

Comment: @Nemgathos, Oh, I am sorry. `WINEPREFIX="$HOME/prefix32" wine msiexec /i SpeechPlatformRuntime.msi` , it should be forward slash before `i`. please try again.

Comment: Nevermind. Writing `WINEPREFIX="$HOME/prefix32" wine msiexec /i MSSpeech_TTS_en-US_ZiraPro.msi` leads to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6M049.jpg).

Comment: @Nemgathos, it means everything is OK. Just proceed to the next steps.

Comment: It finally works and my Ubuntu OS has now become **a lot more** valuable to me! Thank you very much. I have been looking for a solution to this problem for a very long time.

Comment: @Nemgathos, glad that it worked, you are welcome.

Comment: Ok, there is still one problem left. The ZiraPro voice works perfectly fine but I cannot install other voices. If I type `WINEPREFIX="$HOME/prefix32" wine msiexec /i MSSpeech_SR_de-DE_TELE.msi`, only [the first two lines of this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6M049.jpg) will be displayed to me and no window will open up. After starting Balabolka by typing `WINEPREFIX="$HOME/prefix32" wine "$HOME/prefix32/drive_c/Program\ Files/Balabolka/balabolka.exe"`, ZiraPro is still the only voice available. (Note that I downloaded the German voice manually and copied it to the `Program files` folder.

Comment: @Nemgathos, look, `MSSpeech_TTS_en-US_ZiraPro` has **TTS** in its name, however, `MSSpeech_SR_de-DE_TELE` does not have **TTS** in its name. You should specifically download and install files with **TTS** in its name.

Comment: BTW, you were right about Program Files. I used backlashes inside the double quote, so the command was wrong.

Comment: Trying to install `WINEPREFIX="$HOME/prefix32" wine msiexec /i MSSpeech_TTS_de-DE_Hedda.msi` does not work either. It will still show [the first two lines of this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6M049.jpg) and no window will open up. After starting Balabolka, ZiraPro is still the only voice available. The same is true for `WINEPREFIX="$HOME/prefix32" wine msiexec /i MSSpeech_TTS_en-GB_Hazel`.

Comment: I just installed and everything is fine: https://i.imgur.com/vx2qSZ9.png

Comment: Maybe, you will try to downgrade wine version? My version is 4.0. I am not sure about this, but this might help.

Comment: I just realised that I downloaded and copied the files to the wrong directory (-.-). But now, everything works fine!

Answer (score 1):

I followed this github guide [sapi5_on_linux](https://github.com/mjakal/sapi5_on_linux) and got it to work. The most important and relevant line is the following:

```
WINEPREFIX=~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/tts winetricks speechsdk
```

You need to use `winetricks` to install `speechsdk`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I did not encounter the exact problem you are describing myself, but I just created a new TTS utility which could help you as well.
It works offline, for free with AI-based high-quality voice. You can you it everywhere: Firefox browser, PDF reader, chrome, LibreOffice, etc.

You can give it a try, it comes form research on deep learning and AI, and I find it much better than espeak, festival and co. Hopefully you can do without Wine.

Feel free to have a look, I just created a video tutorial with installation steps and DEMO: https://youtu.be/hb1ZVwUcPCU

Download link and Project page: https://github.com/MattePalte/Verbify-TTS

Feel free to leave comment/open issue to discuss new ideas, problems or constructive criticism.

Hoping it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Debian 12. Make sure you have Wine and Winetricks installed.

Creating your 32bit Wine Prefix. I will call it “win7”

```
WINEPREFIX=~/.win7 WINEARCH="win32" winecfg
```

Install these components

```
env WINEPREFIX=~/.win7 winetricks d3dx9
env WINEPREFIX=~/.win7 winetricks msvcirt
env WINEPREFIX=~/.win7 winetricks speechsdk
env WINEPREFIX=~/.win7 winetricks vcrun2008
env WINEPREFIX=~/.win7 winetricks vcrun2010
env WINEPREFIX=~/.win7 winetricks corefonts
```

Install Balabolka

```
env WINEPREFIX=~/.win7 wine ./setup.exe
```

Run Balabolka

```
env WINEPREFIX=~/.win7 wine "C:/Program Files/Balabolka/balabolka.exe"
```

At this point SAPI5 was working with English voices in Balabolka, but other languages were throwing the error `Can not synthesize the speech: OLE error 8004503A`

To fix this I had to install [KobaSpeech lib](https://www.kobaspeech.com/downloads/)
I used this one "`KobaSpeech 3 With Vocalizer Allison - English (United States).exe`" and renamed the file to `KobaSpeech.exe` for the easier installation process.

```
env WINEPREFIX=~/.win7 wine ./KobaSpeech.exe
```

I am using SAPI5 voices from https://rhvoice.org/ all working great.
I tested Russian & Portuguese.
One more thing when you start Balabolka make sure you export your language locale.

I just created a bash file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export WINEPREFIX=~/.win7
export LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
wine "C:/Program Files/Balabolka/balabolka.exe"
```